# How do I get a sprite to do something while being touched (Android AndEngine)?

Tags: android, touch, sprite, andengine

How do I get a sprite to do something while it's being touched (specifically, I want it to increase in size.) I tried:

```
private void createSpriteOnTap(float x, float y)
    {
        final Sprite yourSprite = new Sprite(x, y, textureRegionForYourSprite, getVertexBufferObjectManager())
        {           
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) 
            {
                //if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
                    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove())
                    {
                        // while player is touching our sprite
                        setScale(scale += 0.1);
                        setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - getHeight() / 2);
                    }

                    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown())
                            setScale(scale += 0.1);
                return true; 
            }
        };
```

But the sprite only increases in size when it's moving or being tapped, not being held. How do I make it increase in size until the user lifts his finger?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you catch a mousedown event inside the sprite region you could use a CountDownTimer for example to start enlarging the sprite.  Mouse up would stop the timer.
See:   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

So here you would start it on mousedown.

```
CountDownTimer spriteScaleTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     // put scaling here
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
     // Max scale size.
 }
 }.start();
```

Then onMouseUp:

```
spriteScaleTimer.cancel();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done it like following this-

```
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
        float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
        flagTouch=true;
    }
    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
        flagTouch=false;
        setScale(1f);
    }
    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
        flagTouch=false;
        setScale(1f);   
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
     if(flagTouch){
         setScale(1.5f);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following code work for you because I have tested it and it worked for me.

```
final Sprite sprite = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, mFaceTextureRegion) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown())
                flagTouch = true;

            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp())
                flagTouch = false;

            setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - getWidth() / 2,
                    pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - getHeight() / 2);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

            if(flagTouch)
                setScale(scale+=0.1f);
        }
    };
```